Cannot receive notification in my expo project
i have been trying to set up the expo push notification forever now and can't seems to figure out why i can't get any notification
_layout.tsx
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
// import * as Device from 'expo-device';
// import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { useColorScheme } from "@/components/useColorScheme";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { GlobalProvider } from "../context/GlobalProvider";
// import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { NotificationProvider } from "@/context/NotificationContext";

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async (notification) => {
    console.log("Foreground notification received:", notification);
    return {
      shouldShowAlert: true,
      shouldPlaySound: true,
      shouldSetBadge: true,
    };
  },
});

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "(auth)",
};

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLayoutRootView();
  }, []);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (loaded) {
      // This tells the splash screen to hide immediately! If we call this after
      // `setAppIsReady`, then we may see a blank screen while the app is
      // loading its initial state and rendering its first pixels. So instead,
      // we hide the splash screen once we know the root view has already
      // performed layout.
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <NotificationProvider>
        <ThemeProvider
          value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
        >
          <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Stack initialRouteName="(auth)">
              <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="createRequest"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
            </Stack>
          </GestureHandlerRootView>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </NotificationProvider>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

registerForPushNotificationsAsync.ts
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }

  if (Device.isDevice) {
    console.log("Device:", Device.isDevice)
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    console.log("existingStatus:", existingStatus)

    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    console.log("finalStatus:", finalStatus)

    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      throw new Error(
        "Permission not granted to get push token for push notification!"
      );
    }
    const projectId =
      Constants?.expoConfig?.extra?.eas?.projectId ??
      Constants?.easConfig?.projectId;
    console.log("Project Id:",projectId)
    if (!projectId) {
      throw new Error("Project ID not found");
    }
    try {
      const pushTokenString = (
        await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
          projectId,
        })
      ).data;
      console.log("Push Token",pushTokenString);
      return pushTokenString;
    } catch (e: unknown) {
      throw new Error(`${e}`);
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("Must use physical device for push notifications");
  }
}

NotificationContext.tsx
import React, {
    createContext,
    useContext,
    useState,
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    ReactNode,
  } from "react";
  import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
  import { EventSubscription } from "expo-modules-core";
  import { registerForPushNotificationsAsync } from "@/utils/registerForPushNotificationsAsync";
  
  interface NotificationContextType {
    expoPushToken: string | null;
    notification: Notifications.Notification | null;
    error: Error | null;
  }
  
  const NotificationContext = createContext<NotificationContextType | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  
  export const useNotificationGlobal = () => {
    const context = useContext(NotificationContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        "useNotification must be used within a NotificationProvider"
      );
    }
    return context;
  };
  
  interface NotificationProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
  }
  
  export const NotificationProvider: React.FC<NotificationProviderProps> = ({
    children,
  }) => {
    const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [notification, setNotification] =
      useState<Notifications.Notification | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | null>(null);
  
    const notificationListener = useRef<EventSubscription>();
    const responseListener = useRef<EventSubscription>();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(
        (token) => setExpoPushToken(token),
        (error) => setError(error)
      );
      console.log("Push Token:", expoPushToken)

  
      notificationListener.current =
        Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
          console.log(" Notification Received: ", notification);
          setNotification(notification);
        });
  
      responseListener.current =
        Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
          console.log(
            " Notification Response: ",
            JSON.stringify(response, null, 2),
            JSON.stringify(response.notification.request.content.data, null, 2)
          );
          // Handle the notification response here
        });
  
      return () => {
        if (notificationListener.current) {
          Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
            notificationListener.current
          );
        }
        if (responseListener.current) {
          Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
        }
      };
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <NotificationContext.Provider
        value={{ expoPushToken, notification, error }}
      >
        {children}
      </NotificationContext.Provider>
    );
  };

(NOBRIDGE) LOG Device: true
(NOBRIDGE) LOG existingStatus: granted
(NOBRIDGE) LOG Project Id: c4c061d6-d6ff-4681-a7db-bb6dd0cbad8d
(NOBRIDGE) LOG Push Token ExponentPushToken[nDjCS8HRLLS8ja_poKwjj4]
(NOBRIDGE) LOG Notification payload: {"body": "Hello", "title": "Hello", "to": "ExponentPushToken[nDjCS8HRLLS8ja_poKwjj4]"}
(NOBRIDGE) LOG Push notification response: {"data": {"id": "01937bb0-6f10-7c70-9a87-1433fe2cba0d", "status": "ok"}}
My log doesn't show me anything wrong
I have tried to reinstall, reconfigured and rebuild my project multiple time to no avail.
